# Error trying to reattach TFS 2018 Collection to Devops 2022 Server

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, migration

I'm trying to migrate my TFS 2018 environment to Devops 2022. I copied the TFS DBs to a new SQL Server 2019 and started the Devops Installation on a separate front end Server.

I keep running into this error when I run the configuration wizard:

> “TF255356: The following error occurred when configuring the Azure
> DevOps databases: TF400711: Error occurred while executing servicing
> step ‘Update Process Templates’ for component UpdateProcessTemplates
> during UpdateProcessTemplates: The data type of substitution parameter
> 2 does not match the expected type of the format specification… For
> more information, see the configuration log.”

In the configuration log, I think these lines are important:

> "Exception Message: TF400711: Error occurred while executing servicing
> step ‘Update Process Templates’ for component UpdateProcessTemplates
> during UpdateProcessTemplates: The data type of substitution parameter
> 2 does not match the expected type of the format specification. (type
> TeamFoundationServicingException) Exception Stack Trace: at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingContext.FinishStep(Exception
> exception) at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingStepDriver.PerformServicingStep(ServicingStep
> step, ServicingContext servicingContext, ServicingStepGroup group,
> ServicingOperation servicingOperation, Int32 stepNumber, Int32
> totalSteps) at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingStepDriver.PerformOperations(Int32
> stepsToPerform) at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingStepDriver.Execute(Int32
> numberOfStepsToPerform) at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.UpgradeConfigDbDriver.Execute() at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.ConfigureUpgradeConfigDB.Run(ActivityContext
> context)
>
> Inner Exception Details:
>
> Exception Message: The data type of substitution parameter 2 does not
> match the expected type of the format specification. (type
> SqlException) SQL Exception Class: 16 SQL Exception Number: 2786 SQL
> Exception Procedure: prc_SaveFile SQL Exception Line Number: 205 SQL
> Exception Server: SQL2019 SQL Exception State: 1 SQL Error(s):
>
> Exception Data Dictionary: HelpLink.ProdName = Microsoft SQL Server
> HelpLink.ProdVer = 15.00.4326 HelpLink.EvtSrc = MSSQLServer
> HelpLink.EvtID = 2786 HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl =
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink HelpLink.LinkId = 20476"

Any ideas how I can solve this issue? I don't find any details about the error in the eventlog of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the good news is that upgrading a TFS 2018 Team Project Collection directly to Azure DevOps Server 2022 is supported according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started).

Just from the error message you're getting it seems that the upgrade fails because the process template cannot be upgraded. New features sometimes require modifications to the process template and in your case, those modifications cannot be applied because some Team Project(s) likely come with outdated process templates.

What's the history of this Team Project Collection? Does it contain Team Projects that were created with even earlier Team Foundation Server versions?

If so, that might be the problem and you would have to upgrade the process template of those Team Projects first. If you're indeed coming from the old world, that can be a painful process. It is usually done by downloading the process template xml files that you want to apply and then using `witadmin.exe` to apply those xml files to the Team Project to be updated.

A potential starting point on how to do this might be [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/manage-process-templates?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Freference%2Ftoc.json&view=tfs-2018).

Comment: This might be it! i know that this was migrated from 2015 before but have no knowledge if it goes back even more. I will get back to you if I have any update.